# Problema con condición IF .NET

Tags: c#, .net, condiciones

Tengo un problema con la validación IF en general. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente ejercicio tengo que indicar SI si el día ingresada fue Lunes y NO si es otro día, hasta ahí todo ok. El problema llega cuando en vez de poner Lunes (con L mayúscula) pongo lunes (con l minúscula) o luNes, etc, en resumen todas las variaciones que pueda tener la palabra.

El output es NO cuando agrego alguna variación pero la palabra sigue siendo la misma, ¿cómo puedo resolver esto?

//3. Indicar con una leyenda “SI” o “NO” si el texto ingresado es “Lunes”.

```
string dia;

Console.Write("Ingrese un día de la semana: ");

dia = Console.ReadLine();

if (dia == "Lunes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("SI");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NO");
}
```

Comment: Franco no olvides marcar como aceptada la respuesta que más te ayudo, y si lo deseas también puedes dar tu voto positivo a todas las respuestas si están correctas y te ayudaron, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# ofrece diversas formas en que puedes comparar una cadena ignorando mayúsculas / minúsculas.

Si tienes una cadena como esta:

```
string dia = "Lunes";
```

Puedes optar por una de estas:

[`System.String.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-7.0)

<sub>Esta es la opción recomendada para tu caso.</sub>

```
if ( dia.Equals("lunes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
if ( dia.Equals("lunes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) )
```

[`System.String.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0)

<sub>Esta es una opción aceptable.</sub>

```
if ( dia.IndexOf("lunes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 )
if ( dia.IndexOf("lunes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 )
```

[`System.String.ToUpper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=net-7.0) / [`System.String.ToLower`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=net-7.0)

<sub>Estas opciones funcionan, pero crearán una nueva cadena en memoria por cada llamada.</sub>

```
if ( dia.ToUpper() == "LUNES" )
if ( dia.ToLower() == "lunes" )
```

[`System.String.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0)

<sub>Esta opción puede ser imprecisa, pero funciona.</sub>

```
if ( dia.Contains("lunes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
if ( dia.Contains("lunes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) )
```

[`System.String.StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-7.0)

<sub>En este punto, ¿no te ha funcionado ninguna de las anteriores?.</sub>

```
if ( dia.StartsWith("lunes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
if ( dia.StartsWith("lunes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Solo una pregunta respecto a la primera opción, escribí esto y funcionó if ( dia.Equals("lunes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )

La otra que mencionabas if ( dia.Equals("lunes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ) ¿En qué difiere?

¿Y en qué casos puedo usar todas las otras opciones?

Comment: @Franco C# realiza comparaciones basadas en la cultura del equipo en que se ejecuta, tomando en cuenta cosas como las operaciones de cambio del país, configuración de Windows, etc. `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` indica que la comparación debe realizarse ignorando la cultura. `OrdinalIgnoreCase` realiza la compración en base a la cultura, lo que es aceptable a menos que tu aplicación sea internacional y pueda presentar problemas con operaciones de otras culturas. Explicar los casos de uso de las otras opciones es extenso, todo dependerá de la necesidad que tengas en el momento.

Comment: En [esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749662/string-comparison-invariantcultureignorecase-vs-ordinalignorecase) puedes encontrar información detallada. Y no olvides marcar mi respuesta como aceptada si te fue de utilidad.

Comment: La *cultura* depende de la configuración de idioma y regional del sistema. Aunque puedes establecer otra específicamente para tu aplicación y desligarla de la del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la **función ToLower**, la cual devuelve todas las letras de la cadena en minúsculas:

```
if(dia.ToLower() == "lunes")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sí");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No");
}
```

También puedes usar la **función ToUpper** que devuelve todas las letras de una cadena en mayúsculas:

```
if(día.ToUpper() == "LUNES")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sí");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/em-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals#system-string-equals(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) indicando como quieres que sea la comparación.

Por ejemplo, con [`CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) se comparan en base a la configuración regional ignorando las mayúsculas:

```
cadena.Equals(otra, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Más información: [Cómo comparar cadenas en C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings).

Comment: Muchas gracias!